Install openclash in openwrt
I am new to openwrt, i try to  install openclash in fresh new openwrt with following command:
opkg remove dnsmasq && opkg install dnsmasq-full
wget https://github.com/vernesong/OpenClash/releases/download/v0.45.35-beta/luci-app -openclash_0.45.35-beta_all.ipk -O openclash.ipk
opkg update
opkg install openclash.ipk
opkg install luci luci-base luci-compat
reboot

when I restart, luci web doesnot working with error below, what is the problem? thanks
/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/ddns.lua:14: module 'luci.model.ipkg' not found:
no field package.preload['luci.model.ipkg']
no file './luci/model/ipkg.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/luci/model/ipkg.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/luci/model/ipkg/init.lua'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/luci/model/ipkg.lua'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/luci/model/ipkg/init.lua'
no file './luci/model/ipkg.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/luci/model/ipkg.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/loadall.so'
no file './luci.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/luci.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'require'
/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/ddns.lua:14: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
/usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:531: in function 'createindex'
/usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:558: in function 'createtree'
/usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:243: in function 'dispatch'
/usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:121: in function </usr/lib/lua/luci/dispatcher.lua:120>

